# "An internal error occurred while ensuring the default service account exists" while creating Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create Google App Engine using create application option but i am getting below error :

An internal error occurred while ensuring the default service account exists.

Can you please help me with the solution

Tried creating with different location getting same error

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Comment: It is showing this error while creating "An internal error occurred while ensuring the default service account exists." Do you have any idea why this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the default App Engine Service Account is not missing (due to an accidental deletion e.g) from the IAM & admin > Service accounts section of the Cloud Console. It is named after your **project** followed by "**@appspot.gserviceaccount.com**".

If you do not see it, you can recover it by doing for example a REST API call as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting_a_service_account):

```
POST https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/serviceAccounts/[SA-NAME]@[PROJECT-ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com:undelete
```

If the deletion was made more than 30 days ago, the only way left to fix the issue would be to create a new project and use its brand new default Service Account.